# Input type=radio On change get value into a variable

Tags: php, variables, onchange

Need to get selected radio button value stored in a variable and I am not sure how to go about it

```
<input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="happy" id="happy" value="0" checked />
<input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="neutral" id="neutral" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="sad" id="sad" value="2" />
```

I think I can listen to which radio button has been clicked by adding onchange event

```
<input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="happy" id="happy" value="0" onChange="getValue(this)" checked />
<input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="neutral" id="neutral" value="1" onChange="getValue(this)" />
<input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="sad" id="sad" value="2" onChange="getValue(this)" />
```

Now I need to store selected value in $spilldeck = ...............

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 2):

You want to perform a calculation based on the value of the radiobuttons.

You prefer to use php for it, so the data has to be send to the server, otherwise you can't assign the data to a variable, well you can but not a php variable. Then you should use javascript, because php is serverside.

```
<form action="YOURPAGE.php" method="POST">
  <input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="happy" value="0"/>
  <input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="neutral" value="1"/>
  <input type="radio" name="spilldeck" class="sad" value="2"/>
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

This will be the form that you can use. Now you want the data saved to a variable so u can perform a calculation right?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    $spilldeck = $_POST['spilldeck']
}
```

This way your value of the selected radiobutton is stored. Now you want to perform the calculation, because the spilldeck variable is created.

so write:

```
if(isset($spilldeck)){
    your function, calculation whatever
}
```

Afther that you can redirect to an other page or whatever.

Does this solve your question?

Comment: Yes if possible

Comment: Well it is not possible with Php, because php will execute on the server side. Your radiobuttons are in the browser, so if you want to use php you have to submit the form. Otherwise i suggest to use javascript so you can use an eventlistener to save the value to a variable and use it how ever u want.

Comment: i think i can solve your problem but a form has to be submitted. The calculation that you want to do, is that with php or an other language link javascript or ajax ?

Comment: Can you give js code how to do it

Comment: And no... I can't give you the javascript code, u can atleast try it before asking me the complete code for it...

Comment: _"I needed more information..."_ - that's what comments are for.

Comment: i can't comment on the question with 1 reputation...

Answer (score -1):

**Example:**

```
<form action="YOUR_ACTION" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="spilldeck1" class="happy" id="happy" value="0" onChange="getValue(this)" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="spilldeck2" class="neutral" id="neutral" value="1" onChange="getValue(this)" />
    <input type="radio" name="spilldeck3" class="sad" id="sad" value="2" onChange="getValue(this)" />
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $spilldeck1 = $_POST['spilldeck1'];
    $spilldeck2 = $_POST['spilldeck2'];
    $spilldeck3 = $_POST['spilldeck3'];
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: i don't understand why my answer doesn't answer the question. However his problem is with JS. I recommend him PHP. If he don't know how to get postData i can add this solution too.

Comment: _i don't understand why my answer doesn't answer the question_ Because there is no code in your answer.

Comment: Code is not always the solution. U can get the solution over ideas ;)

Comment: Read over [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: thanks for the guide. Maybe now better ? ;)

Comment: I need it before form submit as there is calculations done based on the value before result send via form submit